# how convert internet_connection check code from bloc 7 to bloc 8

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

how this code work in bloc 8 ?
i read Migration Guide in https://bloclibrary.dev/#%2Fmigration= but cant do this.

plase help me.

```
class NetworkBloc extends Bloc<NetworkEvent, NetworkState> {
  NetworkBloc() : super(ConnectionInitial());

  StreamSubscription _subscription;

  @override
  Stream<NetworkState> mapEventToState(NetworkEvent event) async* {
    if (event is ListenConnection) {
      _subscription = DataConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
        add(ConnectionChanged(status == DataConnectionStatus.disconnected
            ? ConnectionFailure()
            : ConnectionSuccess()));
      });
    }
    if (event is ConnectionChanged) yield event.connection;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class NetworkBloc extends Bloc<NetworkEvent, NetworkState> {
  NetworkBloc() : super(ConnectionInitial()){
    on<ListenConnection>(_onListenConnection);
  }


  
  void _onListenConnection(ListenConnection event, Emitter<NetworkState> emit) async* {
      emit.forEach(
        DataConnectionChecker().onStatusChange,
        onData: (status) => status == DataConnectionStatus.disconnected
            ? ConnectionFailure()
            : ConnectionSuccess());
    
  }

}
```

No need to have a separate ConnectionChange event here.